# Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL

Tags: android, webview

I'll be using my app, loading html pages into the webview, and sometimes the WebView seems to take a lot longer to load a page... when it does that, I see the message spammed to logcat :

```
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.880: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.890: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
09-15 11:15:56.900: D/FRAMELOADER ISSUE :(13523): Frameloader fetching extra UA String - UAProfURL
```

What does it mean ? How can I avoid it ?

Comment: Can you provide the url?

Comment: In my case, it's AdMob that is doing it.

Answer (score 2):

UAProf - User Agent Profile describes the capabilities of a device, and it could be useful for AdMob network to return a more suitable advertising.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAProf

UAProfUrl points to XML describing such device properties. 
Basically UAProf is generated by Android Webkit, and `WebView` should take it from here.

This info depends on build properties from `/system.build.prop`, and maybe for some device it's not available, or it's a Webkit issue.

This property could be manually set by HTTP-header `X-Wap-Profile`. 
Here is some profiles lists
http://validator.openmobilealliance.org/cgi/validation/profiles.html
http://delicon.sourceforge.net/profiles.html

I'm not sure this info is real used by AdMob (or other sites), so we can try to set some fake.
For example, this is profile for Galaxy Nexus

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("X-Wap-Profile", "http://wap.samsungmobile.com/uaprof/galaxynexus.xml");
webView.loadUrl("url", headers);
```